# Can i only use the auth on firebase?

Tags: postgresql, flutter, spring-boot, authentication, firebase-authentication

i'm a junior developer and i'm trying to build a small full stack app using flutter, i want to create my backend in springboot and PostgreSQL but i'm having some problems with my login, so i thought aout using firebase for my auth only, is it a good idea? and if so, is it possible?

I tried looking in the firebase website, but to no avail

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Whether or not it's a good idea is a matter of opinion, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally possible to use this service with your free tier resources that Firebase gives to everyone. I've checked and on the Spark plan you can have 3000 daily active sessions using Email, Social logins and anonymous sessions.

Their docs are very clean and can help you with everything. Here is the link to the [Firebase Authentication docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth?authuser=0&_gl=1*16962xx*_ga*MTQ3MDg3NzgxMy4xNjgyNTE4NTA0*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4Njg0MzczOC4zLjEuMTY4Njg0Mzc2MS4wLjAuMA..&hl=pt-br).

Today, the best way to authenticate final users on our platforms is using OAuth 2.1 protocol following by its Authorization Code Flow. This will be the method that Firebase Authentication will give to you if you follow their docs. It's highly recommended that you don't try to create your own way to authenticate if you are not aware about the best practices and your application needs to be secure.

For study purposes, I recommend that you understand how to deal with Firebase Authentication and on the future try to implement your own way and compare themselves.

On flutter you can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, i think 3000 daily users it's absolutely fine, i will read the docs!